# Operating system error code 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)

Tags: sql-server

I tried the following code to try and bulk load into a table in my SQL Server.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.CentralRepository_Associate_Details 
FROM '/1CAAP/1413/data/csvtest1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';')
```

and got the following **error** :

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "/1CAAP/1413/data/csvtest1.csv" 
could not be opened.     
Operating system error code 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

I guess error code 3 is a permission error.

Just a request: I'm not very good as far as stuff like this is concerned. So explanation in layman terms would be really helpful.

Comment: First of all the path should be as Ilya explained in windows path format i.e `C:\Files\FileName.CSV` and you are also missing the `ROWTERMINATOR` clause of your bulk insert.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I need to run the file from the server. So is there anyway I can do it using bulk insert? or is there another alternative to do the same.

Comment: Is this file located on your network share? If this is the case you can still use the UNC Path `\\ServerName\Folder\FileName.CSV` , Just make use Your login has permissions on that Network Share. and correct your synatx for bulk insert, as you are missing `ROWTERMINATOR` clause of your bulk insert statement.

Comment: Hi, My login does have permission and will look into the row terminator clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx

```
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
  3 (0x3)
  The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Try the Windows path format, `C:\1CAAP\1413\data\csvtest1.csv`, instead of *nix. Does the file even exist at that path?

Edit: Run `xp_fileexist '/1CAAP/1413/data/csvtest1.csv'`

Comment: Yes the file does exist.

Comment: Hi Thanks, The thing is we are using unix servers to run the job. And it's throwing this error. Plus unix does not support windows path I presume? So is there any other alternative that is available to move the bulk data to the table?

Comment: How are you running SQL Server on a unix box? The cron job or what have you issuing  the command might run on *nix, but the path needs to be understood by SQL Server, which I presume runs on Windows, no?

Comment: Try running `xp_fileexist '/1CAAP/1413/data/csvtest1.csv'` on that server, what does it say?

Comment: Ok, that was way too technical. anyway I'll tell you what I do. I have a job in pentaho that runs a script. I place that job on my server and then run the job in putty. 

xp_fileexist throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the service account which you are you using in the job, does not have access to the file path. This could be because of the lack of trust between the two domains - the one which hosts the UNIX server and the one where your file resides. I guess the solution is to setup a service account which has pass through (between domains) authentication access.